# Build an executable with only the libraries wanted?

Tags: python, executable, cx-freeze

I am using `cx_freeze` to build standalone executables. The following is an example for such `setup.py` file.

```
import os
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'
exe = [Executable("main.py")]
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\tcl\\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\tcl\\tk8.6'
options = {
  'build_exe': {
    'includes': ['scipy.io', 'scipy.spatial.ckdtree'],
    'include_files': [r'C:\\Users\\dmurugesan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll',
                      r'C:\\Users\\dmurugesan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll',
                      r'C:\\Users\\dmurugesan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\'
                      r'pyqt5_tools\\platforms\\qwindows.dll'],
    'packages': ['pkg_resources._vendor', 'numpy', 'scipy', 'pydub', 'soundfile', 'cffi'],
  }
}

setup(name="lTBA", version="0.4", description='To be added',
  options=options, executables=exe)
```

Eventhough after mentioning the list of libraries to be included, the build is included all the libraries present in the environment! How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

You can define the libraries that you'd like to exclude:

```
'build_exe': {
    'excludes': ['library1_name', 'library2_name'], 
    # ...
}
```